# Create an array that grows at a regular interval on Matlab

Tags: matlab, timer

I have been thinking about how to create an array that grows at a regular interval of time (for instance every 5 seconds) on Matlab.

I figured out 2 ways, either using tic/ toc or timer function. Later this program will be complexified. I am not sure which way is the best but so far I am trying with using timer.

Here is what I have tried :

```
clc;

period=5;%period at which the file should be updated
freq=4;
l=freq*period;
time=[0];

a = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period',period,'TimerFcn',{@time_append, time,l,freq},'TasksToExecute',3 );
start(a);

function [time]=time_append(obj,event,time,l,freq)
        time_append=zeros(l,1);
        last_time=time(end)
        for i=1:1:l
            time_append(i)=last_time+i/freq;
        end
        time=[time;time_append];
end
```

After compiling this code, I only get a time array of length 1 containing the value 0 wheras it should contain values from 0 to 3x5 =15  I think it is a stupid mistake but I can't see why. I have tried the debug mode and it seems that at the end of the line `time=[time;time_append]`, the concatenation works but the time array is reinitialised when we go out of the function. Also I have read that callback function can't have output. Does someone would know how I could proceed? Using globals? Any other suggestion?

Thank you for reading

Comment: Appending arrays is generally slow, better would be to preallocate to the final size if possible. If you want to update a file, i.e. write to file, use `fprintf('my_file', 'a')`, i.e. the append-flag. Can you elaborate a bit more on what your ultimate goal is, as this smells of an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/325771)?

Comment: Later, input datas (from sensors) will be appended in a set of files with a real time update.  From these datas, processing should be carried out and some output datas should be writen on an output file in realtime. For now, the input datas are not updated in real time. I only have at my disposal datas file from after a measurement session. I would like to artificially generate in real time the output datas by taking into account for instance

1) after the 5 first second, only the datas corresponding to 5 seconds of measurement; 2) after 10 seconds, the datas corresponding to 10 seconds ect

Comment: I was initially thinking to update the datas directly in arrays but maybe I could update a new file. I will try that thank you !

Comment: Making `time` a global variable would solve your issue. It’s not a nice solution, but it’s the only one I can see that doesn’t require to rethink the whole problem.

Comment: Do note that, in a system that occasionally creates extra data, you wouldn’t have a growing array. I would expect every packet of data coming in would be received as a separate packet, and processed as such, not appended to the previous packets in a single large array.

Comment: One obvious problem with your approach is that the array might grow indefinitely, but you don’t have infinite memory for an infinite array. Another obvious problem is that processing would take longer and longer for every packet you receive, at some point it’ll take longer to process the day than you have before the next one comes.

Comment: Yes I haven't think that much so far, I just wanted to try for short duration. But indeed at the end I should include a limit number of data by erasing the first one when a threshold is reached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using [nested functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html). Nested functions allow you to access "uplevel variables", and you can modify those. Here's one way to do it:

```
function [a, fcn] = buildTimer()

period=5;%period at which the file should be updated
freq=4;
l=freq*period;
time=0;

    function time_append(~,~,l,freq)
        time_append=zeros(l,1);
        last_time=time(end);
        for i=1:1:l
            time_append(i)=last_time+i/freq;
        end
        time=[time;time_append];
    end
    function out = time_get()
        out = time;
    end

fcn = @time_get;

a = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate',...
    'Period',period,...
    'TimerFcn',{@time_append,l,freq},...
    'TasksToExecute',3 );
start(a);
end
```

Note that the variable `time` is shared by `time_append` and `time_get`. The `timer` object invokes `time_append`, and updates `time`. You need to hand out the function handle `time_get` to retrieve the current value of `time`.

```
>> [a,fcn] = buildTimer; size(fcn()), pause(10); size(fcn())
ans =
    21     1
ans =
    61     1
```

Comment: Nice application of nested functions! I had not thought of using them as callbacks like this.

Comment: Who needs `classdef` when you've got `function`?

Comment: Couldn't agree more! :D

Comment: Tahnk you also for this suggestion ! I managed to do what I wanted by writing in files but this could be useful for further applications.